# Calling void function problems

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array

Hello I have problems calling the void initialize() function in my code. I am supposed to get an array that looks like this

```
//cccccccccccccccccccccccccc
  cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxhhhhhhhxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxhhhhhhhxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxhhhhhhhxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxhhhhhhhxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc
  cccccccccccccccccccccccccc//
```

where the array is defined in Initialize() and the variables come from  FIN , SteamPipe and GridPT classes. My code is giving me the first set of answers before the array but when it gets to the array I only get the symbol '?' that is what it's been designated in the class GridPT.
I think that the way I am calling the void function is wrong or there is something wrong passing the variables? I already tried taking out the const but still the same.
here is my code .h file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<istream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int maxFinHeight = 100;
const int maxFinWidth = 100;

class Steampipe
{
private:
  int height, width;
  double steamTemp;

public:
  Steampipe (int H = 0, int W = 0, double sT = 0.0)
  {
    height = H;
    width = W;
    steamTemp = sT;
  }

  // Access function definitions
  int getWidth()const{return width;};
  int getHeight()const{return height;};
  double getSteamTemp()const{return steamTemp;};
  void setWidth(int dummysteamwidth) {width = dummysteamwidth;};
  void setHeight(int dummysteamheight){height = dummysteamheight;};
  void setSteamTemp(double dummysteamtemp){steamTemp = dummysteamtemp;};

  // Access function definitions
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& , Steampipe& ); // YOU MUST DEFINE
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& , const Steampipe& ); // YOU MUST DEFINE
};

class GridPt
{
private:
  double temperature;
  char symbol;

public:
  GridPt(double t = 0.0, char s = '?')
  {
    temperature = t;
    symbol = s;
  }

  // Access function definitions
  double getTemperature()const {return temperature;};
  char getsymbol() const {return  symbol;};

  void setTemperature (double T=0) {T=temperature;}
  void setsymbol (char S='?'){S=symbol;}
};

class Fin
{
private:
  int width, height; //width and height of fin
  int pipeLocationX, pipeLocationY; //grid location of lower left corner of steampipe
  double boundaryTemp; //temperature of fin surroundings
  Steampipe Pipe; //steampipe object - COMPOSITION
  GridPt GridArray[maxFinHeight][maxFinWidth]; // array of GridPts - COMPOSITION

public:
  int getwidth() {return width;}
  int getheight() {return height;}
  int getpipeLocationX(){return pipeLocationX;}
  int getpipeLocationY(){return pipeLocationX;}
  double get_boundarytemp(){return boundaryTemp;}
  void setwidth (int w){w=width;}
  void setheight (int h){h=height;} 
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& , Fin& ); // YOU MUST DEFINE
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& , const Fin& ); // YOU MUST DEFINE

  void initialize(); // YOU MUST DEFINE
};

void Fin::initialize()
{
  int j(0) ,i(0);
  for ( i = 0; i < height; i++)
  {
    for (  j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
      if (   j == pipeLocationX && i == pipeLocationY
          && i <  Pipe.getHeight() + pipeLocationY
          && j < Pipe.getWidth() + pipeLocationX)
      {
        GridArray [j][i].setTemperature(Pipe.getSteamTemp());
        GridArray [j][i].setsymbol('H');
      }
      else if (j == (width -1) || i == (height -1) || j == 0 || i == 0)
      {
        GridArray [j][i].setTemperature(boundaryTemp);
        GridArray [j][i].setsymbol('C');
      }
      else
      {
        GridArray [j][i].setTemperature((Pipe.getSteamTemp() + boundaryTemp)/2);
        GridArray [j][i].setsymbol('X');
      }
    }
  } 
}



istream &operator >> (istream & in, Fin& f)
{
  int   ws, hs; 
  double  ts;
  char comma;

  cout << "Enter the height of the fin (integer) >>> ";
  in >> f.height;

  cout << "Enter the width of the fin (integer) >>> " ;
  in >> f.width;

  cout << "Enter the height of the streampipe (integer) >>> ";
  in >>hs;
  f.Pipe.setHeight(hs);
  cout << "Enter the width of the steampipe (integer) >>> ";
  in >> ws;
  f.Pipe.setWidth(ws);
  cout << "Enter coordinates of lower left corner of steampipe (X,Y) >>> ";
  in >> f.pipeLocationX >> comma >> f.pipeLocationY;

  cout << "Enter the steam temperature (floating point) >>> ";
  in >> ts;
  f.Pipe.setSteamTemp(ts);
  cout << "Enter the temperature around the fin (floating point) >>> "; 
  in >> f.boundaryTemp;
  return in;
}

ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Fin& t)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  stream << "The width of the fin is " << t.width << endl;

  stream << "The height of the fin is " << t.height << endl;

  stream << "The outside temperature is " << t.boundaryTemp << endl;

  stream << "The lower left corner of the steam pipe is at " 
         << t.pipeLocationX <<      "," << t.pipeLocationY << endl;

  stream << "The steampipe width is " << t.Pipe.getWidth() << endl;

  stream << "the steampipe height is " << t.Pipe.getHeight() << endl;

  stream << "The temperature of the steam is " << t.Pipe.getSteamTemp() << endl;

  for ( i = 0; i < t.height; i++)
{
    for (  j = 0; j < t.width; j++)
    {
        if (j == t.pipeLocationX && i == t.pipeLocationY && i < t.Pipe.getHeight() + t.pipeLocationY && j < t.Pipe.getWidth() + t.pipeLocationX)
        {
            t.GridArray [j][i].getTemperature();
            stream<<t.GridArray [j][i].getsymbol();

        }
        else if (j == (t.width -1) || i == (t.height -1) || j == 0 || i == 0)
        {
            t.GridArray [j][i].getTemperature();
            stream<<t.GridArray [j][i].getsymbol();
        }
        else
        {
            t.GridArray [j][i].getTemperature();
            stream<<t.GridArray [j][i].getsymbol();
        }

    }stream<<endl;
}   

  int coorx(0),coory(0);char comma;

  stream << "Enter the coordinates of the gridpoint of interest (X,Y) >>> "
         << endl;
  cin>>coorx>>comma>>coory;
  stream<<"The temperature at location ("<<coorx<<","<<coory<<") is "
         << t.GridArray << endl;

  return stream;
}
```

and my driver file cpp is:

```
#include "pipe.h"

int main()
{
  Fin one; 
  cin >> one;
  one.initialize();
  cout << one;

  return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions will be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: At least try to have somewhat indented code and to narrow it down to the actual problem. This is just too painful otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, there's such a big chunk of code there that editting it to be more readable seems like far too much effort! Concise, well-formatted example, please.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the following is wrong:

```
void setTemperature (double T=0) {T=temperature;}
void setsymbol (char S='?'){S=symbol;}
```

It must be:

```
void setTemperature (double T=0) {temperature = T;}
void setsymbol (char S='?') { symbol = S;}
```

As an aside: It is not a good habit to place function definitions in your header (unless it's a template), rather put them in a source-file with just the declarations in the header.

In your code you also use `t.GridArray` in your output-stream directly:
`stream<<t.GridArray;`
 This will not work.
It is not a function, or a type that the ostream will understand.
Use the i and j variables you have declared and step through each element of the array to print them, same as when you initialize the array.

Comment: thank you Slashmais, Well the teacher gave us part of the header. We are supposed to initialize the function pipe and make the array, We can't move any function in the source code. BTW i just switched temperature and symbol sides and still not working. All I get is the address of the function =002e8728

Comment: thank you again Slashmais, I did what you said and it is looking better now. Only problem is that I am not getting the inside rectangle filled with 'H'. But Ill keep looking for anything that I might be missing.

Comment: @lolo1116: that's the way to learn, play with the code, make changes and see what happens. A VERY GOOD HABIT that you should start to do from now on is when you have working code, to back it up before you change it. That way you can copy it back when your change flops, and try again. (and trust me it's 'when' not 'if' ;)